# IntelliJ PyCharm promiscuously installing packages

Tags: package-manager

I have a Python/Pandas project where I tried to import and call `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split()`. It wasn't working and I went to check if I'm missing some packages in `project interpreter`. To my surprise, the "sklearn" package had been automatically installed, and it certainly doesn't look like a legitimate package. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I wasn't able to find more info on that package. Do I need to worry? Why did PyCharm automatically install something for me from an "UNKNOWN" author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm does not automatically install packages. What very likely happened is that you added `import sklearn` to the top of your file, and then used the `install package` quickfix. After you add an unresolved import, a red light bulb will appear, and you can choose to install the package with the name of your import, in this case `sklearn`.

The other ways to install packages from PyCharm are: installing them based on a project's requirements.txt file (a yellow bar will appear at the top of the editor, and you need to click 'Install' on it), manually using the package editor in the settings screen, or if you type the commands in the Terminal window.

Furthermore, the package you're worrying about is empty: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sklearn/0.0. All it says is that you should download `scikit-learn` instead.

Comment: One of the maintainers of the `sklearn` package is also a maintainer of the `scikit-learn` package, so this seems to be intentional.